# Increase variable for class

Tags: php, list, class, variables

I have a piece of code that generates list items. Is there a way I can have it so that the list item has a class, and every time a list item is created, the class number can increase by one?

For example, the class would be "listitem1", then the second "listitem2" and so on, so that after each list item is created, the variable number increases by 1. Here is the code I am using:

```
<ul id="servicelist" class="clearfix">
        <?php if(get_field('homepage_service')): ?>
            <?php while(the_repeater_field('homepage_service')): ?>
                <li class="listitem"><img src="<?php the_sub_field('service_image'); ?>" width="144" height="103" /></li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </ul>
```

I could do this in Flash (as3) but am unsure of how it works in PHP exactly. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [PHP variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php):

```
<?php $count = 0; ?>
<ul id="servicelist" class="clearfix">
    <?php if(get_field('homepage_service')): ?>
        <?php while(the_repeater_field('homepage_service')): ?>
            <?php $count++; ?>
            <li class="listitem<?php echo $count; ?>"><img src="<?php the_sub_field('service_image'); ?>" width="144" height="103" /></li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that is much the same as the way as I am used to

Answer (score 0):

Just use a simple counter -

```
<ul id="servicelist" class="clearfix">
    <?php if(get_field('homepage_service')):
      $count = 1; 
    ?>
        <?php while(the_repeater_field('homepage_service')): ?>
            <li class="listitem<?php echo $count ?>"><img src="<?php the_sub_field('service_image'); ?>" width="144" height="103" /></li>
            $count++;
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </ul>
```